# Wildcard DNS for only first level subdomain

Tags: dns, wildcard-subdomain

I want to know how to set a wildcard DNS for only first level subdomain, example:

```
user.example.com     // valid
www.user.example.com // invalid
```

I have my BIND zone domain configured like this:

```
; example.com
$TTL 86400
@       IN      SOA     ns.example.com. domain.example.com. (
                                        2014021001 ; Serial
                                        28800      ; Refresh
                                        1800       ; Retry
                                        604800     ; Expire - 1 week
                                        86400 )    ; Minimum

                IN      NS      ns
                IN      NS      ns1

ns              IN      A       1.2.3.4 ; An IP
ns1             IN      A       1.2.3.4 ; An IP

@               IN      A       1.2.3.4 ; An IP
*.example.com   IN      A       1.2.3.4 ; An IP
www             IN      A       1.2.3.4 ; An IP

@               IN      TXT     "v=spf1 a mx -all"
```

And my Apache virtual host config is like this:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
  ServerAdmin domain@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ServerName example.com
  ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
  CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
  ServerAdmin domain@example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps.example.com
  ServerAlias *.example.com
  ServerName apps.example.com
  ErrorLog logs/apps.example.com-error_log
  CustomLog logs/apps.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help!

Comment: how you sole this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it in the DNS - a wildcard will match one or *more* DNS labels.

You *may* be able to do it in the Apache server, perhaps by using `mod_rewrite` to match on the supplied hostname and returning a 404 error if the hostname is invalid.

Comment: That's how I did before I asked this question, but thanks for clarifying that this is not possible. ;)

Comment: @alnitak how to do with mod_rewrite ?